# Assmbly bind failure - not logging?

Tags: c#, .net

I made some changes in two projects. I tested on the development system and all is well. I then copied the 2 dll's to the test system. Running the functionality I get the following error.

Note that I have made numerous changes in project A (DataAcquisitionTests). Tested that in the test system and it works. I get this issue only when Project A (DataAcquisitionTests) and project B (Microsoft.MSInternal.AmalgaTest.Common.Core. I'll refer to this as Common.Core) is involved. Change here is minor, Project A uses a new property from Project B (Common.Core).

> Initialization method ... threw exception.
>   System.MissingMethodException: System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   not found: 'System.String
>   Common.Core.TestConfiguration.Configuration.get_WorkingDirectory()'..

This is because Project A (DataAcquisitionTests) is invoking property from project B(Common.Core) but it is not to be found in project B(Common.Core). 
I guess I have not replaced the dll in the correct location. So I ran fuslogvw.exe.

I get some logs, but I do not see the failed logs.
I looked for the dll's logs (Dll of DataAcquisitionTests which is the property invoker).

This is the log for dll A (DataAcquisitionTests).

> ```
> * Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/30/2015 @ 8:27:05 AM) *
> ```
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
> completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
> executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0/Common7/IDE/TestResults/amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00/Out LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = QTAgent32_40.exe Calling
> assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter,
> Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101
> 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.DLL.config LOG: Using
> host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Post-policy reference: DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396 LOG: GAC Lookup was
> unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program
> Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0/Common7/IDE/TestResults/amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00/Out/DataAcquisitionTests.DLL. LOG: Assembly download was
> successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101
> 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.dll LOG: Entering
> run-from-source setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
> DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396 LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns
> assembly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.dll. LOG: Assembly is loaded in
> default load context.
>
> ```
> * Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/30/2015 @ 8:27:05 AM) *
> ```
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
> completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
> executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0/Common7/IDE/TestResults/amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00/Out LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = QTAgent32_40.exe Calling
> assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter,
> Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101
> 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.DLL.config LOG: Using
> host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Post-policy reference: DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396 LOG: GAC Lookup was
> unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program
> Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0/Common7/IDE/TestResults/amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00/Out/DataAcquisitionTests.DLL. LOG: Assembly download was
> successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101
> 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.dll LOG: Entering
> run-from-source setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
> DataAcquisitionTests, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396 LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns
> assembly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 12.0\Common7\IDE\TestResults\amv3tst_MTAENGDDPLVC101 2015-04-30 08_27_00\Out\DataAcquisitionTests.dll. LOG: Assembly is loaded in
> default load context.

Comment: Its really hard to follow the log without knowing the actual names of "Project A" and "Project B".

Comment: Have modified it, it has Project names now.

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx